# Exception while trying to call a method in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby. My sample code is giving me this exception:

```
C:/Users/abc/RubymineProjects/Sample/hello.rb:5:in `<class:Hello>': undefined method `first_method' for Hello:Class (NoMethodError)
    from C:/Users/abc/RubymineProjects/Sample/hello.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Process finished with exit code 1

My code is :

```
class Hello
  def first_method
    puts "Hello World"
  end
  first_method()
end
```

I am using RubyMine 4.5.4.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are trying to call `first_method` on the class -- and `first_method` is an instance method. To call an instance method, you need to use an instance of the class. To make an instance of the class, you can use `SomeClass.new`. So, to use your method, try this code (same code as @megas):

```
class Hello
  def first_method
    puts "Hello World"
  end
end

Hello.new.first_method
```

Answer (score 3):

In contrast to the other answers (but to achieve the same output), if you did want that method call to work within your class you could simply define the method as a class method:

```
class Hello
  def self.first_method
    puts "Hello World"
  end
  first_method()
end

#=> "Hello World"
```

I found the following link to be helpful in explaining the difference between the two in a little more detail: http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Hello
  def first_method
    puts "Hello World"
  end
end

Hello.new.first_method
```